# how to use flask_migrate in my gunicorn+flask proj

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, migrate

I have a proj using flask+gunicorn+MySQL, and the directory is like this:

```
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── login.py
│   ├── system.py
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── task.py
│   └── view.py
├── config.py
├── gunicorn.conf
├── requirements.txt
├── tests
│   └── testurl.py
└── wsgi.py
```

There is a function factory in app/**init**.py, like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

def create_app(conf):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DATA_BASE_PATH
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(app=app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    app.register_blueprint(blueprint=view, url_prefix='/view/')

    socketio.init_app(app, async_mode=None)
    login_init(app)

    return app
```

and in the file wsgi.py, i have:

```py
from app import create_app
from config import app_conf
from app import socketio

app = create_app(app_conf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app=app, host=host, use_reloader=False)
```

If i want to run this porj, i use:

```sh
gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf wsgi:app
```

now i want to use flask-migrate to update the MySQL table change automaticly, but i am wondering where shoud i init the migrate? i have tried do that in wsgi.py or in app/**init**.py, but neither works...
please give me a hand, thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You should init your Flask Migrate in your app/init.py file such as:

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app() 
    migrate.init_app(app)  
    # your original code here
```

then to run the migration, you can just run in the cmd shell `flask db migrate`

Comment: did like you said, it says: ` * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
Usage: flask db migrate [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "application.app", an ImportError was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/lbj/work/gitlab/far/application/app/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from app.task import task
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` when i run

Comment: yes, you need to install python-dotenv to take advantage of your .env or .flaskenv files (that will have the environment information to properly do the flask db migrate). For instance, you will need to pass the correct db connection URL and db name in the .env.